# Activity+Fragment: add fragment in code vs. xml

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there a difference in adding a fragment to an activity layout in code or adding it in xml?

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, CardViewFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
}
```

vs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.example.CardViewFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="tag_cardview_fragment" />
```

Comment: shouldn't be voted down, it's a fair question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the code method, you can dynamically change which fragment is loaded, like on a button click or any other user-generated event.

Answer (score 1):

**Both xml and code are almost similar**. If you had used that xml code inside activity's layout then we could expect little difference in Fragment behavior.

If you put that `xml` in activity then fragment will create/load automatically and **after** that you can get its instance.

**But here:**

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, CardViewFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
}
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.example.CardViewFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="tag_cardview_fragment" />
```

You are creating fragment instance **first** and then loading it in to activity.